# Updating install4j application

Tags: java, windows, install4j

I am working on packaging Java 7 application for Windows using install4j. My application requires restart of the pc after installation. When the user first install the application he is prompted if he wants to restart the pc and thats perfect. I also use the automatic update feature via the updates.xml. The problem is when the aplication updates it restarts the pc without prompting the user. I need the user to be prompted regardless is it an update or first installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the installer runs in unattended mode, it will not ask the user about a reboot if one is required. You can pass the argument

```
-Dinstall4j.suppressUnattendedReboot=true
```

to the installer in order to prevent any reboot. Search for the action names "Set installer arguments" in your updater configuration, you can enter the above argument there.

There is no way to ask the user anything in unattended mode.